# How to spawn cosmetically modified cars outside LS-Customs in GTA-Online on PS4

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online, ps4

Two days ago I found a cosmetically modified (no engine/performance modification applied) car just outside LS Customs in La Mesa District on GTA Online. And it sold for about 19K. (nice way of making easy money in GTA ONLINE)

Since then I can't reproduce the conditions that spawns those modified cars..

Can anyone tell me how-to or how-frequently we can obtain those beautiful pre-modified cars ?

I am playing GTA ONLINE on PS4 (I don't know if it is any different on other consoles)

Comment: None of your requested tags are ones we would use, I'm afraid.

Comment: thx for rapid response Frank.